# Centering an image and a two-column layout.

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, positioning, two-column

Here's what I'd like to do. Place a centered image, and then have two columns of text centered below it. I did the following:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{image}

\begin{multicols}{2}
lots of text
\end{multicols}
\end{center}
```

All that happens is that the image is centered, but the two column block is aligned left. I tried variants where I used two center environments, one for the image and one for the multicol. I also tried using `\centering` instead, and even tried encapsulating the multicol inside a minipage. All to no avail.

It's a minor issue, but it's driving me nuts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update: Here's an MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=3in]{plan}
\end{center}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:[image: Example of bad centering]

Comment: As always a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be nice so that people can see for themselves and test their solution.

Comment: I'll do that. however, my example has an image in it, and I don't know how to create the nifty image snippets that others on this forum seem able to do.

Comment: You can load `graphicx` with the demo option to have images replaced with a black box.

Comment: Do you want the text in the `multicols` to be centered (ragged on both sides) or the whole block placed centered relative to the outer text? The latter implies that the `multicols` width is smaller then the width of the outer text.

Comment: the latter. I'd like the block centered with respect to the page, like the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `multicols` needs to be smaller than the outer text so it can be centered. This can be done by using the `minipage` environment with a smaller width then `\textwidth`. If it has the same width it is technically already centered when printed with justification. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. Using a enumeration environment with short text like in your MWE is not a good way to show that. Enumerations are differently aligned than normal text.

Here my code which includes some normal text and an enumeration. The `blindtext` package is used to insert some dummy text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=3in]{plan}
  \begin{minipage}{3in}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \blindtext
    \end{multicols}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{3in}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
            \item 4
            \item 5
            \item 6
            \item 7
            \item 8
            \item 9
            \item 10
            \item 11
            \item 12
            \item 13
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{trivlist}
\item[]\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{image}
\end{minipage}

\begin{multicols}{2}
lots of words
\end{multicols}
\end{trivlist}
```

The `trivlist` environment is just to insert some space above and below the whole construction. If you need indented margins for the two column text, use

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{image}
\end{minipage}

\begin{multicols}{2}
lots of words
\end{multicols}
\end{quote}
```

possibly changing `\leftmargin` and `\rightmargin`.